# Highcharts treemap top and left borders missing

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have created a treemap using Highcharts, but the top and left borders are missing. I've been reading through the docs but can't find anything which will help.

I have created a Codepen **[here](https://codepen.io/ahdigital/pen/ayxmKb)**. You can see that against the black background the borders along the top and left sides of the series aren't visible. I think they're there, but maybe the chart is offset on the X/Y by a pixel or something.

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
  colors: ['#263542', '#3d4d5d', '#41474d', '#515961', '#292e33', '#24445e'],
  lang: {
    thousandsSep: ','
  }
});

Highcharts.chart('treemap', {
  chart: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)'
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      colorByPoint: true,
      borderColor: 'rgb(71, 116, 135)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
          textOutline: 'none',
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          fontWeight: '300',
          fontSize: '1rem'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    valuePrefix: '£'
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'treemap',
    layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
    data: [{
      name: 'Indices',
      value: 230000,
    }, {
      name: 'Forex',
      value: 120000,
    }, {
      name: 'Shares',
      value: 55000,
    }, {
      name: 'Pension',
      value: 55000,
    }, {
      name: 'ISA',
      value: 20000,
    }]
  }],
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

#treemap {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>
<div id="treemap"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, even though axes (xAxis/yAxis) are not visible in treemap chart, they have impact on it, by covering left and top part of the border. Setting the `offset` property in both axes with small value (e.g. 1) will move them away from plot area, uncovering missing border parts.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.offset
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.opposite

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/20oh9c3d/

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The example treemap from Highcharts by default has the borders missing - they should implement your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment yet, so this is not really and answer. But I found that if you change your `borderWidth` to 2, then the border becomes visible. To me this indicates that the margin or padding of your element is covering up the border in the top left section of the element for some reason. Hope this can point you in some sort of direction.